# How to encode accent text in android?

Tags: android

I want to display accent mark text in my android app.I want to display café from my data base in my app.
Whenever I search cafe in my data base[sqlLite] it always shows cafe instead of café.

Comment: share your code that you tried

Comment: Can you describe me for how to show accent mark display.? Rest I will handle. 
Thanks for responding